# Ancova using variable selected from loop (R)

Tags: r, loops, static-analysis, mixed-models

I have 1,000 dependent variables (y) to use in Ancova. Independent variables (x) is the same in all models.

```
Yvar1, Yvar2, …, Yvar1000, x1, x2
1       2          5       11  16
2       3          6       18  23
```

I need an R code that replace `example$Y.to.use` values for each Yvar.

I tried this:

```
for (i in 1:1000){ 
example$Y.to.use<- example$paste("Yvar",i, sep="")

# Error: attempt to apply non-function

paste("fitted.model",i)<-lme(log(Y.to.use+1)  ~ x1*x2, data=example, random=~1| Exp/Person)
} 

# Error in paste("fitted.model", i, sep = "") <- lme(log(Y.to.use+1)  ~ x1*x2  : target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I will create a table with coefficients from each fitted model of each Yvar.

Comment: You cannot use character values of variable names interchangably with the variables themselves. You cannot use characters with the "$" and "~" constructions. If you want to be dynamic, you should use the indexing operator `[,]` which does allow you to pass variable names as characters

Comment: Look on this page for "One common mistake": http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html . Same goes for variable assignments the the formula "~" syntax.

Comment: Construct formula for each iteration using `paste` inside `formula`.

Comment: Thanks David. Your suggestions worked well.

Comment: lme(as.formula(paste("log(Y.to.use", i,"+1) ~ x1*x2", sep="")), data =example, random=~1| Exp/Person)

Comment: Can someone help to save the results in a matrix?

fitted.models <- lapply{
  for (i in 1:1000){  
 lme(as.formula(paste("log(Y.var", i,"+1) ~ x1*x2", sep="")), data =example, random=~1| Exp/Person)
  }}